# Sort data in Local Storage based on data field

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Edit: Someone flagged this as a duplicate, I already read the question that marked as duplicate on this one. But I think this question is different since mine is related to local storage, and the other one isn't.

**tl;dr: Is it possible to sort the data in Local Storage based on data field?**

Right now I am trying to use local storage in an application I'm building in Cordova.

Since Cordova based on JS, everything seems normal with my code. Except I want to sort the data in local storage for some reason.

And I am confused, can we sort the order of the data based on the field?

i.e I have this json stored in local storage: `[{a:1,b:1},{a:3,b:3},{a:2,b:4}]`. And I want to sort it based on `a`, so it will be like this `[{a:1,b:1},{a:2,b:4},{a:3,b:3}]`.

If it is possible, how to do it? And where do I need to do it? Before save the data to local storage or when me call out the data from local storage?

Comment: Quick answer ~ `arr.sort((a, b) => a.a - b.a)`. Your second question about *"when"* is too broad to be answered

Comment: Presumably before putting it in storage it is an array, so just use the `.sort()` method on the array before you use `JSON.stringify()`. (Or use `.sort()` after you call `JSON.parse()` when you get it out of storage.)

Comment: @Phil i see, so its how it is work. And yeah, you are right about it became too broad to be answered. But thanks anyway to have your time answer my question

Comment: @nnnnnn hmm, your one is correct, i can just do something like that. Thanks for the asnwer !